# UnassignedReferenceException when accessing variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to insert the stop code into this code. But I could not do it. How can I turn off the isKinematic feature of isKinematicStop object?

I get this Error:

> I get this error UnassignedReferenceException: The variable
>   isKnematickstop of ObstacleController has not been assigned. You
>   probably need to assign the isKinematickstop variable to the
>   ObstacleController script in the inspector.
>   UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent [Rigidbody2D] () (at C:
>   /buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/G‌​ameObjectBindings.ge‌​n.cs:35)
>   ObstacleController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D col)
>   (at Assets / esplades / Scripts / ObstacleController.cs: 52)

Original Script.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class ObstacleController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float hitPushBack;
        public GameObject hitEffect;
        public Sprite[] sprites;

        public void Awake()
        {
            if (sprites.Length > 0)
                GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)];
        }

        void OnEnable()
        {
            GameManager.GameStateChanged += OnGameStateChanged;
        }

        private void OnGameStateChanged(GameState newState, GameState oldState)
        {
            if (newState == GameState.GameOver)
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            GameManager.GameStateChanged -= OnGameStateChanged;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            //Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, RotationVariables.direction * Mathf.Abs(RotationVariables.maxAngle));
            //transform.root.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.root.rotation, targetRotation, RotationVariables.rotationDelta);
        }

        public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
        {
            if (col.collider.tag == "Player")
            {
                hitEffect.transform.position = col.contacts[0].point;
                hitEffect.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                GameManager.Instance.playerController.anim.Squeeze();
                GameManager.Instance.playerRigidbody.AddForce(col.contacts[0].normal * hitPushBack);
            }
        }
    }
```

(Col.collider.tag == "Player") in isKinematickstop.GetComponent  (). IsKinematic = false; How can I run it?
I did it..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float hitPushBack;
    public GameObject hitEffect;
    public Sprite[] sprites;
    //------------------------------------------
    public GameObject isKinematickstop;
    //------------------------------------------


    public void Awake()
    {
    if (sprites.Length > 0)
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)];
}

void OnEnable()
{
    GameManager.GameStateChanged += OnGameStateChanged;
}

private void OnGameStateChanged(GameState newState, GameState oldState)
{
    if (newState == GameState.GameOver)
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    GameManager.GameStateChanged -= OnGameStateChanged;
}

void Update()
{
    //Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, RotationVariables.direction * Mathf.Abs(RotationVariables.maxAngle));
    //transform.root.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.root.rotation, targetRotation, RotationVariables.rotationDelta);
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        hitEffect.transform.position = col.contacts[0].point;
        hitEffect.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        GameManager.Instance.playerController.anim.Squeeze();

        //------------------------------------------
        isKinematickstop.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic= false;
        //------------------------------------------
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try it or there's just nothing happening? And are you sure the collision occurs.

Comment: This is C# not Unityscript

Comment: I get this error

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable isKnematickstop of ObstacleController has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the isKinematickstop variable to the ObstacleController script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent [Rigidbody2D] () (at C: /buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/GameObjectBindings.gen.cs:35)
ObstacleController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D col) (at Assets / esplades / Scripts / ObstacleController.cs: 52)

Comment: @SinanSaglam You need to assign a gameobject to `isKnematickstop` in the inpsector.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @CNuts 
How can i assign it?
Please help me.

Comment: @halfer Sorry. I am very new and I could not solve this problem.

I will not do it again

Comment: @Programmer Could you add how to assign objects in the inspector in your answer. I don't think we have an answer that explains that. We could reuse this question for further same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the `isKinematic` of Rigidbody2D from the isKinematickstop GameObject with `isKinematickstop.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;`.

I noticed that you have already done that. I believe that you want to do this on the GameObect that enters the trigger. If that's true then `col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;` should do it.

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        hitEffect.transform.position = col.contacts[0].point;
        hitEffect.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        GameManager.Instance.playerController.anim.Squeeze();

        //------------------------------------------
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
        //------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> With the  UnassignedReferenceException: error:

You have to assign the GameObject to the  isKinematickstop  slot.

[image]

Comment: I did this. But it's not working. Could you take a look at the script here? Please be very important to me.https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84034

Comment: @SinanSaglam Could you be more specific, _it's not working_ doesn't give us any information. What happens after you've assigned the GameObject?

Comment: @SinanSaglam You have to drag the GameObject with the Rigidbody2D to the `isKinematickstop` slot in your script. If the animated image I put in my answer does not answer your question, I suggest you stop your game or whatever you are doing and do a basic [Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial). If you don't know how to assign a GameObject to a variable, it's a sign you need to learn the basics. The easiest way to do that is to follow one of the Unity's project tutorials.

Comment: @Programmer thanks ..@CNuts 
I want to do this.http://imgur.com/Yi2JXL7

Comment: @SinanSaglam That image does not explain what errors you're getting when you apply the solution in this answer. And looking at the image you probably want the collided object to stop so you should try the first solution that Programmer gave.

Comment: @Programmer  Col.gameObject.GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> (). Simulated = false; I did it.
Thank you very much.@CNuts