# Can not set instance of UI image in script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have been having problems setting an instance of ui image in my following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using Image = UnityEngine.UI.Image;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class changeimage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Image imageobject;
    // public Sprite myFirstImage;
    Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load("watermalon", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void ClickToChange2()
    {
        //imageobject = GetComponent<Image>();
        //Debug.Log(imageobject);
        imageobject.sprite = myFruit;
    }
}
```

Error is: **Null reference to imageobject**

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the `myFruit` variable in a function.

Do `Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load("watermalon", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;` in a function.

```
Sprite myFruit;

void Start()
{
    myFruit = Resources.Load("watermalon", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
}
```

If you don't do this, you will get this error:

> Load is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or
>   instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called
>   from MonoBehaviour

**EDIT**:

Another problem is that nothing is assigned to the `imageobject` variable from the Editor.

Since `imageobject` is a public variable, drag any GameObject with the `Image` component attached to it to the public imageobject slot. You can see how to drag objects to variable slots from the image from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455231/3785314) answer.

Comment: myFruit is working fine it has the instance of image, the problem is with imageobject it is not being set to the instance and referee to null.

Comment: No. `myFruit` is not working fine. Fix that first part of my answer then check the Edit which answers your second problem. You have two problems not just one.

Comment: yes I am having that error load is not allowed to be called, what to do next ?

Comment: Look at the answer I left. Can't you see it? Look how I did it in the Start function....

Comment: the error are gone, but still the imageobject is refereed to null,have done drag object to variable slot part too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Image imageobject = new UnityEngine.UI.Image();
```

you are just defining instance but not create from the class.

Comment: by doing this, error CS0122: `UnityEngine.UI.Image.Image()' is inaccessible due to its protection level. this error occured